# How to clear line-through for an element in a table row?

Tags: css, html-table, text-decorations, strikethrough

I'm having trouble "clearing" a line-through that I'm using on a table row. I don't want the line-through effect on the link. I'm changing the tr class dynamically with Javascript so I would like to keep it as simple as possible.

My current code:

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr class="table-item">
<td>Text</td>
<td><a href="#">Delete item</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.table-item td {
text-decoration: line-through;
}
.table-item a {
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-decoration#Notes) says: “Text decorations draw across descendant elements. This means that it is not possible to disable on a descendant a text decoration that is specified on one of its ancestors.”

Comment: That is indeed good information, thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was playing with it in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R4U44/). Seems like the only way to do it is to wrap the other content that you want the `line-through` on in another element, like a `span`.

Update: code from jsFiddle, as requested:

```
<table>
  <tr class="table-item">
    <td><span>Text</span></td>
    <td><a href="#">Delete item</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.table-item td span {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, why anyone has not pointed out. This is actually possible.

Here is the link to fiddle

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rfv6gosL/)

> Adding `display: inline-block` on element which you dont want to show line-through will do the trick.

Try:

```
.table-item td {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
.table-item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your browser requirements (won't work in old IE) you can use:

```
.table-item td:first-child {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is using span, out of the question?

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;  
}
td span{
text-decoration: line-through;
}

<table>
<tr class="table-item">
<td><span>Text</span></td>
<td><a href="#">Delete item</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Or are you strictly using code injection to style the strikethrough?